# Auto indent plain list content?

Tags: org-mode, indentation

When I make a plain list like this:

```
- Pizza making 
  This is an elaborate process that 
  involves many years of training.
```

Usually I have to manually press <kbd>TAB</kbd> on every new line. 
Can this be automated so that org automatically inserts a tab for me if I press return once, and doesn't insert a tab if I press return twice?

**[EDIT] Solution:**
Pressing <kbd>C-j</kbd> gets the job done.

Comment: Does `C-j` work?

Comment: omg, fastest answer ever. Yea, that's exactly what I was looking for. I'd totally accept this as a complete answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use <kbd>C-j</kbd> that calls `newline-and-indent`.

Since you didn't know about that one, you might be also interested in
<kbd>M-j</kbd> that calls `indent-new-comment-line`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you could have a look at org-mode... it is way cooler than text lists and is nowhere complicated either.

Sorry... I couldn't put it in comment since it wanted a higher reputation there.

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort to post an answer. If you look at the tag list, I'm already using org-mode :-).

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev- Okay... didn't notice that... :)